# Cache memory temporal locality and spatial locality principles

Tags: cpu-cache

How does cache memory take advantage of both temporal locality and spatial locality principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loads data in "blocks". Hence, data close together will be loaded together - space locality

It gets rid only of the most unused data - temporal locality

Answer (score 0):

Consider block size as 20B and integer array of 5Elements each of 4B, we know array is stored in contiguous memory locations, consider the base address of Array as 0x0000, the moment you access the very first element it will be miss, because the block you are referring haven't refered before, so for the first element it will be miss, when you the second element it will be hit, because the moment the you access the first element the whole brought into Cache memory like this it will be hit for 3,4,5the elements also (Spatial locality) , you keep accessing the same variable for ex:- sum += 1, here you are accessing variable sum again and again so when you access it first it will be miss, after that it will be unless the block contains the variable has been replaced.

This how cache memory takes advantage of spatial and temporal locality.

Comment: ((Try find a cache with cache block size not a power of two.) What if the first of those 5 elements is in one cache block, and the end in the next one?)